# Запуск Maven приложения на Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, getter

Привет!
Есть Maven проект (web). Везде отсутствуют методы getter и setter.
Так как используется библиотека lombok проект компилится без проблем.

Но при запуске прилоежния на сервере Tomcat выдает ошибки как раз те, что отсутствуют эти самые методы getter и setter.

Как решить пробелму? Добавлять методы вручную долго, так как файлов много. Можно ли это сделать как-то автоматически для всего проекта или есть другие варианты решения проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте pom.xml и ваш war. Попадают ли в папку lib эта библиотека и её зависимости.

Comment: Разобрался. Нужно было запустить файл lombok.jar библиотеки lombok. Тем самым устанавливается штука в Eclipse, которая игнорирует отсутствие этих методов, как будто бы они есть в проекте. И все заработало!